# Is there any cross-platform multi-currency wallet?

Tags: wallet

I know about http://ufasoft.com/coin/
but this is only for windows.

main goal is to put in on dropbox (or same syncing service) and have access to wallet from any of my PC's with any system on it.

and yes, there are a lot of web wallets, but i'm looking for something local